# unable to send pdfs stored in mongo gridfs with python requests module to an API endpoint

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I am new to MongoDB and working first time with MongoDB gridfs

I have inserted n numbers of PDF(eg: 100) in form of MongoDB gridfs using pymongo

Below is the code to save data in MongoDB gridfs

```
import os
import pymongo
import base64
import gridfs

PDF_ROOT_PATH = 'pdfs' # folder containing n number of pdfs
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = myclient['test_db']
collection = db["test_collection2"]

for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(PDF_ROOT_PATH):
    for file_ in files:
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
        file_abs_path = os.path.join(root, file_)
        fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)
        with open(file_abs_path, "rb") as f:
            encoded_string = base64.b64encode(f.read())
        with fs.new_file(
            chunkSize=800000,
            filename=file_) as fp:
            fp.write(encoded_string)
```

[image]

now i want to retrieve this 100 PDFs from gridfs and send a post request to Django endpoint one by one (100 post request for 100 PDFs) which saves this PDF in data base making 100 records.

Below is the code to retrieve data from MongoDB gridfs and make POST requests containing the pdf to drf api

```
import pymongo
import requests
import gridfs
import base64

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient()


db = myclient['test_db']
collection = db["test_collection2"]

API_URL = r'http://localhost:8000/upload/'

fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)
pdfs = fs.find()

for pdf in pdfs:

    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Token {}'.format('12a9ed0e58802ea3d1e8e96bcb7b9arerd'),
    }

    data = fs.find_one(filter=dict(filename=pdf.filename))
    with open(pdf.filename, "wb") as f:
        r = requests.post(
            API_URL,
            files={'file': f.write(base64.b64decode(data.read()))},
            headers=headers,
            verify=False,
        )
```

problem is when it reaches Django API endpoint, sent PDF file is empty

```
 def perform_create(self, serializer):
        logger.info('Inside create')
        file_name = self.request.FILES['file'].name
```

[image]

when hit from postman, file is reflecting.

[image]

the Django endpoint works as expected with the postman, with PDF file but it is giving issue with the MongoDB gridfs. what i am doing wrong?

Please help me resolve this.

thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry , "wb" means write by bytes,how django read it after you write in `f`?It is not allowed to read. Try  `b+` mode,and do `f.seek(0)`  after wirte into, have a try.

Comment: Or use BytesIO  replace open a file in local disk? may faster and less tmp file.

Comment: @bigpang . i tried with the b+ but didn't work, I have added the code how i have save the PDF to MongoDB gridfs

Comment: @young-minds1  Try mode `b+` and split two steps about read from grifs and wirte to new file.after write to new file,do `seek(0)`? I thought the mode `b+` and `seek(0)` can help you .

Comment: @bigpang i am confused. can you please write it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import pymongo
import requests
import gridfs
import base64

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient()


db = myclient['test_db']
collection = db["test_collection2"]

API_URL = r'http://localhost:8000/upload/'

fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)
pdfs = fs.find()

for pdf in pdfs:

    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Token {}'.format('12a9ed0e58802ea3d1e8e96bcb7b9arerd'),
    }

    data = fs.find_one(filter=dict(filename=pdf.filename))
    with open(pdf.filename, "b+") as f:
        f.write(base64.b64decode(data.read()))
        f.seek(0)
        r = requests.post(
            API_URL,
            files={'file': f},
            headers=headers,
            verify=False,
        )
```

or try BytesIO

```py
import pymongo
import requests
import gridfs
import base64

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient()


db = myclient['test_db']
collection = db["test_collection2"]

API_URL = r'http://localhost:8000/upload/'

fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)
pdfs = fs.find()

for pdf in pdfs:

    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Token {}'.format('12a9ed0e58802ea3d1e8e96bcb7b9arerd'),
    }

    data = fs.find_one(filter=dict(filename=pdf.filename))
    f = BytesIO()
    f.write(base64.b64decode(data.read()))
    f.seek(0)
    r = requests.post(
        API_URL,
        files={'file': f},
        headers=headers,
        verify=False,
    )
```

In my thoughts:

1. f.write() return  `None`,which set to the value of 'file' in dict.So you never meet error when you use mode `wb`,which is not allowed reading.
2. apis would read from a file like class,when you use `b+`,the pointer is at the end of the file after you write data into file.So move the pointer to the head of the file is necessary.
3. It is not necessary to save a tmp file in local disk,BytesIO is a file like class,which is duck type. Have a try?
4. In my memory(means I am not sure ), the data you get from mongodb, is also a duck type, which means you may use like below(If you did not do base64 when save a file):

```py
import pymongo
import requests
import gridfs
import base64

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient()


db = myclient['test_db']
collection = db["test_collection2"]

API_URL = r'http://localhost:8000/upload/'

fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)
pdfs = fs.find()

for pdf in pdfs:

    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Token {}'.format('12a9ed0e58802ea3d1e8e96bcb7b9arerd'),
    }
    r = requests.post(
        API_URL,
        files={'file': data },
        headers=headers,
        verify=False,
    )
```

Comment: with first solution. now file is getting sent. but is creating a file in the local disk and then sending it. and with BytesIO again same problem is persisting.

Comment: @young_minds1 I do not understand .You mean solve it by the first way ,or all of them are useless?

Comment: with first solution problem is getting solved but its creating files on local disk which is not wanted. I tried with BytesIO, like you said it wont create a file on local disk but it is not solving the issue, with BytesIO file is not getting sent.same problem persists

Comment: Sure `seek(0)` after write? In my thoughts, both solution will by the same....

Comment: i did f.seek(0) after write but isn't working, rest two of the solutions are working. just BytesIO is not working.

Comment: If you can use the last one, use `pdf` as a file like (duck type),  I thingk  it is the best way. But  the second way about `BytesIO`, not useful,  take me  hard to understand. You can just take  the last solution, or show more  codes about the use about  BytesIO.